# Нужны ли прописные буквы: "Стратегическая сессия Блока корпоративных продаж"?

Tags: прописная-строчная

В апреле прошла Стратегическая сессия Блока корпоративных продаж.

(Блок корпоративных продаж – это подразделение компании, а не самостоятельная структура).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**В апреле прошла стратегическая сессия блока (отдела) корпоративных продаж.**

С прописной буквы обычно пишутся имена собственные: название компании или событие (сессия), если оно особо важное и имеет собственное название, например: Всероссийская сессия...

Блоки, отделы, текущие сессии – это обычно нарицательные названия (строчная буква).